# I have accidentally unpublished android app from play store ,now how can i republish It again?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, keystore, publishing

My app was already on Playstore when i put updated version on playstore I accidentally unpublish app from play store. How can I republish it again.

Comment: you have to change the version of your new app then you will able to publish it. e-g(if old one have this version 1.1.1 the the new one must b other than that 1.1.2 or some thing else

Comment: i think there is an option of Republish app. at least in my case it is showing

Comment: k.so will it available for new user also?

Comment: open your App Dashboard page in developer console. you might find Republish App option beside Submit update (which would be disabled). if this does not work try as @MHamzaJaved suggested.

Comment: done with republish app option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can republish your app using the **Republish app** Button present on the top right corner like the one in the screenshot below :
[image: screenshot from play console]

Comment: Great :) here is more detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45773365/1911652