# How to republish an app after unpublishing it?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I recently unpublished my app. Now I'm not able to find the option for republishing it. I've tried incrementing the version number and re-uploading.

**Note: This question was asked for older Play console.**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Latest **Google play Console** there are some changes in Locations.

You can find it under :

```
Setup / Advance settings / App availability
```

[image]

Comment: When you re-published how long did it take to be visible on the play store?

Comment: I'm very curious of this too. When republishing, did it have to go through another review?

Comment: @Fazberry did u get to know, how long did it take to visible in play store

Answer (score 61):

Select app go to Store presence then select pricing and distribution you will find option to publish and unpublish the application

[image]

Comment: Would download count,ratings and reviews get restored?

Comment: Yes all things will be restored.

Comment: Under the App Availability section, I can see "Your app is currently unavailable on the Play Store." The app was removed for the SMS_READ permission. We have replaced all apks with policy compliant apks. How to republish now ?

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar, how long does it takes to republish the app?