# Republish android app after unpublushing, What happens to the admob revenue, for that time when app is unpublushed?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have an app, and I have received a notice from Google play regarding policy violations, To solve the policy violations I need some time, but the time given by Google Play to solve the policy violation is not sufficient.

Can I unpublish the app for some time, and republish it after solving the policy violation.
I have read this: [How to republish an app after unpublishing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45773305/how-to-republish-an-app-after-unpublishing-it)

And it looks possible.

What will happen to the AdMob revenue, that I am getting through this app, for the time when the app is unpublished?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, publish app on AppStore is not compulsory for ad revenue or AdMob,
so if you will unpublish your app means no one can access your app on the app store but who already downloaded or accessing already they will see your ads and everything,
So means you can continuously earn money from ad Revenue,
This is my answer based on previous app development experience.